# Getting an int value out of an object

Tags: c#, casting

When I use the following code it feels like I'm going wrong somewhere.

```
object obj = 1;
int i = int.Parse(obj.ToString());
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can use TryParse for better exception handling. However, it will not be 'simpler' than this.

Comment: Your way is fine, but there are other methods for conversion also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, what is *actually* in the `obj` ? If it is just a boxed `int`, then simply cast to unbox:

```
int i = (int)obj;
```

For less predetermined content you might also try:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

which will handle a number of scenarios and doesn't add an extra `string` in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
object obj = 1;

// Option 1: Convert. This will work when obj contains anything
// convertible to int, such as short, long, string, etc.
int i = Convert.ToInt32(obj);

// Option 2: Cast. This will work only when obj contains an int,
// and will fail if it contains anything else, like a long.
int i = (int)obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast:

```
object obj = 1;
int i = (int) obj;
```

This is called static cast.

For your information, there is another cast called dynamic cast which can only work with reference types (types that can have the null value), so not in this case (int is a value type):

```
object obj = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date = obj as DateTime;
```

The difference between the two methods is that if the casted object doesn't have the required type, it will raise an exception in the first case (static cast), and it will return null in the second case (dynamic cast).